# How do I get Google Alerts into My Google Reader when I have a Google Apps Account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-reader, google-alerts

Would like to use Google Alerts with my Google Apps account and manage via Google Reader. It appears that one can't associate a Google Alerts created/managed under a Google Apps account and send it to a "feed" the same way one can do this from a standard Google account. Wonder whether there is a way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set myself up with a feed through my `Google Alerts` on my `Google Apps` account.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to http://www.google.com/alerts
2. Make sure you're signed in with your Google Apps account
3. Setup your alert
4. Choose `Feed` in the `Deliver To` section
5. Allow the feed to be setup through your apps account google reader

The following steps are apply if you don't have your regular `Google Reader` account setup through your `Google Apps` account *(I don't)*.

1. Within your Google Apps account Reader area select the Alert feed
2. From the Feed Settings drop-down choose `View Details and Statistics`
3. Copy the feed address
4. Sign in to your regularly used Google Reader account
5. Click `Subscribe`
6. Paste in the URL that you copied to your clipboard

***Disclaimer***: I have a paid for Google Apps for Business account. I don't know if this works for the free Google Apps accounts.

Comment: Thanks Dez... I also have the for pay Google account. It turns out that the feed option was way down at the bottom of the list of various email aliases I have because I have multiple domains...

Comment: @Kendor Hah! That one almost tripped me up as well.